# When I change the orientation and if the player is started, it automatically goes to stop

Tags: ios, swift

I have a player that plays the track. after changing orientation I check the state `player!.currentTime().seconds` and -  it is reset.

how to make that when the track is started, it is not reset after changing orientation but continues to play from the same second. 
I check change orientation and input this code, but this don't work.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if(player != nil){
            if !isPause {
                print("currentTime player\(player!.currentTime().seconds)")
                player!.play()

            }
        }
}
```

print - `currentTime player0.0`

my action, tap play btn:

```
    //MARK: P L A Y   &   P A U S E


 @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) { if playbackSlider.value < 30 {
            if player?.rate != 0{
                isPause = true
                print("currentTime \(player!.currentTime().seconds)")
                player?.pause()
                actionButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_play"), for: .normal)
                playIndicator.isHidden = true
                playIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }else{
                player?.play()
                print("currentTime \(player!.currentTime().seconds)")
                isPause = false
                actionButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_pause"), for: .normal)
                playIndicator.isHidden = false
                playIndicator.startAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
```

Thx.

Comment: add some condition to prevent execution of code written in viewWillAppear

Comment: I add code, what I do, when change orientation

Comment: call play method only if player.rate value is 0

Comment: let me know if this works, actually this works i am sure.

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar but print("player rate = \(player!.rate)")
always  - player rate = 0.0  in viewwilltransition.

Comment: it means before viewWillTransition gets called you are calling player.pause or re-instantiating player. are you?

Comment: can you share complete code of ViewController

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar I'm update question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158852/discussion-between-dattatray-deokar-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in viewWillTransition you are re-instantiating the player. add some condition to prevent this scenario. Issue will resolve.

```
        guard player == nil else {
        return
    }
```